# Specify Starting Offset for HTML5 Input Elements

Tags: cakephp

```
<input name='data[User][images][]' id='images' type='file' multiple="" />
```

I know that the above works and allows for multiple file upload in html5, but I want to start the data[User][images][] array from some offset other than zero. I already tried:

```
<input name='data[User][images][2]' id='images' type='file' multiple="" />
```

But that just makes it so only 1 file's info is stored in offset 2 to be uploaded.

I know how to work my code so I don't need to do this, but now I'm simply curious if there might be a way to keep multiple file upload while telling it to start from a non-zero offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not a feature of HTML but of the server-side language or framework. The only "support" offered by HTML is that element names may contain square brackets.

It doesn't look like CakePHP supports any special behavior for form-submitted arrays (though I'm not very familiar with it). Your best bet is probably the [PHP manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays), which doesn't mention anything about starting from an offset other than zero.